# Weighing hypotheses after seeing the data vs. Consistent learning

Tags: machine-learning, learning

In the chapter about *nonuniform learning* in the book "*Understanding Machine Learning*, S. Ben David et al." (its free online version [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)), the authors wrote:

> if we commit to any hypothesis **before seeing the data**, then we are guaranteed a rather small estimation error term
> $$
> L_\mathcal{D}(h)\le L_S(h) + \sqrt{\frac{log(2/\epsilon)}{2m}}.
> $$

The statement clearly suggests that the error bound might be different if we still commit to the same hypothesis but **after** seeing the data. However, I don't know what the authors mean by "after seeing the data".

I think that committing to a hypothesis after seeing the data would change the learning setting from *non-uniform learning* to *consistent learning* but I'm not sure it's correct or not?